# How to make a collection_select in rails that only displays options with a specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building an app where a user can customize components in a pc(system), based on components that are available in their respective tables (eg. motherboards table, cpus table.. etc)

I would like the user to be able to select the components via a dropdown select in the system form.

I have been able to achieve this by using collection_select like this

```
<%= collection_select(:system, :motherboard_id, Motherboard.all, :id, :model, prompt: true) %>
```

However, the collection_select displays all components in the table, and I wish to only display those components that have an `available: true` attribute.

I have tried

```
<%= collection_select(:system, :motherboard_id, Motherboard.any? {|mobo| mobo.available?} , :id, :model, prompt: true) %>
```

which results in `undefined method 'map' for false:FalseClass` [screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnrY2.png)

I thought about adding a `before_save` callback that checks each items availability, but if that's not the only way to get it to work, I think that would be a poor decision in terms of UX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<%= collection_select(:system, :motherboard_id, Motherboard.where(available: true), :id, :model, prompt: true) %>
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: @disc0ninja If this works for you, please mark Shannon's post as the answer for your question.